# Xamarin Forms: Remove gap between grid elements

Tags: xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin Forms page, I'm seeing the following gap between two grid elements in Android (emulator and phone), and the same gap is there if I swap the grids around:

```
<StackLayout x:DataType="auctions:AuctionViewModel">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#444" Padding="2" Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="FilterButtonAll" Text="All" Clicked="SetFilterToAll" StyleClass="NoStyle" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Button x:Name="FilterButtonWatchlist" Text="Watchlist" Clicked="SetFilterToWatchlist" StyleClass="NoStyle" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button x:Name="FilterButtonWithdrawn" Text="Withdrawn" Clicked="SetFilterToWithdrawn" StyleClass="NoStyle" Grid.Column="2" />
        <Button x:Name="FilterButtonMyVehicles" Text="My Vehicles" Clicked="SetFilterToMyVehicles" StyleClass="NoStyle" Grid.Column="3" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#222" Padding="10,5" Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="17" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="{Binding Auction.OverallStatus}" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="12" />
        <Label Text="{Binding TimeSinceUpdate}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="12" />
    </Grid>
```

This results in the following:

[image: Black gap between elements]

How can I remove the black gap between the two grey elements?

Comment: you need to set the Spacing of your StackLayout.  It defaults to 6

Comment: Thanks. Can you add that as an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the Spacing of your StackLayout. It defaults to 6

Answer (score 0):

You have a property for Grid called RowSpacing.

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
   //your content here
</Grid>
```

Comment: the gap he's talking about is between two different grids in a StackLayout, not within a single grid

Comment: Ahh yes, my bad. Your comment on his question should be the correct way to do this